Does 2 Samuel 6:23 and Samuel 21:8 affirm that you could be adopted into tribal affiliation?
In 2 Samuel 6:23 it says that Michal had no children until the day that she died, but then later on in 2 Samuel 21:8 it says that she had five children, I was discussing this with a friend of mine who is a Catholic and one of his claims is that this proves that you sometimes can be adopted into the tribal affiliation, how would you respond to this claim?

I can't respond directly to his argument, since I don't understand it. (He points to verses that have nothing to do with tribal affiliation.) But I can explain 6:23 the way the classical commentaries (Rashi and Radak, for example) do. It means "she had no further children", meaning from that point on. (Also, some of those same commentators interpret 21:8 as referring to adoptive rather than biological motherhood.)
